# Running simple Hadoop map/reduce tutorial

Tags: java, hadoop

Any ideas why the simple Hadoop map/reduce tutorial is flagging up an error for me. This is the code, copied directly from Apache's tutorial:

```
public class Mining {

public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            output.collect(word, one);
        }
    }
}

public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        int sum = 0;
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            sum += values.next().get();
        }
        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(Mining.class);
    conf.setJobName("wordcount");

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
    conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);
}
}
```

The error is at compile-time and is:

```
The type Mapper is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
```

I've read elsewhere this can be caused by using outdating Hadoop jar files in your project. I'm using the newest stable jar, hadoop-core-1.2, and I've tried with 0.20 as well. Any suggestions as to what the problem is?

**Edit - List of imports:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
```

Comment: Here is exactly the answer to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832949/hadoop-word-count-example-for-1-2-1-stable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your imports once. Perhaps you have mixed the old and the new APIs in your program. Also, I would suggest you to use the new API, i'e **mapreduce** instead of **mapred**.

HTH

Comment: I've included my imports now. So you think mapred is causing the problems? I tried changing mapred to mapreduce, but now all the extends and implements parts complain because they want the mapred versions

Comment: It will. If you want to use the old API make sure you don't have any import from the new API.