# HADOOP - Reduce Phase Hangs on Simple MR Job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

Here is a simple map reduce job.  Initially this is just a simple way of copying files in an input directory to an output directory.  The Map phase completes, but the reduce phase just hangs.  What am I doing wrong?  It is a small amount of code, here is the whole job:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class MapDemo {

    public static class Map extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, NullWritable> {
        private Text word = new Text();
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = value.toString();
            word.set(line);
            context.write(word, NullWritable.get());
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, NullWritable, Text, NullWritable> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<NullWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            context.write(key, NullWritable.get());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(configuration, "MapDemo");
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(10);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }

}
```

It executes until here and then just hangs:

```
$ hadoop jar target/map-demo.jar /Users/dwilliams/input /Users/dwilliams/output
2013-09-16 11:51:19.131 java[6041:1703] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
13/09/16 11:51:19 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/09/16 11:51:19 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/09/16 11:51:19 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/09/16 11:51:19 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/09/16 11:51:19 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201309150844_0012
13/09/16 11:51:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/09/16 11:51:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
... then nothing
```

Whats wrong here?  How do I fix this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the TaskTracker logs as there can be **n** reasons behind it.

Comment: Can you tell me where that might be located?

Comment: Sure, inside $HADOOP_HOME/logs(if you haven't changed the default logs locaiton). I need content of the file which looks like **hadoop-dontariq-tasktracker-BANL119158415.local.log**

Comment: I reformated my name node and it worked.  Aye!

Comment: Hmm..not a very neat solution..what if you are on a production cluster?

Comment: I know, but now I dont have logs to show you :(

Comment: Not an issue. Keep Hadooping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to reformat namenode and restart daemons.  This was on my mac osx, probably related to sleeping.

Comment: Hello @David Williams : Did you find the exact cause of the problem? I have never faced this on my mac. Do let me know if you find something unusual. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Tariq, thanks for checking up.   I haven't had time yet, but one thing I noticed is when I have a pseudo distributed cluster of 1 on my Mac osx, it periodically just fails in ways I don't understand, and j think its related to sleeping, power saving etc, things that don't happen on a real server.  Have you encountered things like this?

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for the response. My box runs continuously[atleast when something is running on it ;)] so never faced any issue due to power settings. I'll test it once and see if that is the case.

Comment: Would really help, and would upvote this, if you gave the code to do the reformat/restart here

Comment: For sure.  `$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/stop-all.sh` then `$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop namenode -format` and then `$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/start-all.sh`.  It destructive though, so use only as a last resort.

Comment: I have a little blog post on getting mapping setup and demoed on a MAC OSX as well if helpful http://asciirain.com/wordpress/2013/10/03/simple-but-powerful-concept-transforming-big-data-with-hadoop-map-reduce/

Comment: @DavidWilliams Hi David, I am facing exactly same issue with hadoop 1.2.1 and I tried the reformatting namenode and restarting daemons, but its not working for me. Mine is OS X yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was memory. I was using VirtualBox and I used the default 512M memory. After increasing the memory to 2G, everything worked.